# Which elements of the frontpage can be customized per site?

Tags: support, homepage

What are various things which can be added to the frontpage *of a single site* to include some information to the users? (As opposed to stuff which is displayed on all Stack Exchange sites.)

So far I have seen:

- A banner on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/). (Two paragraphs : "Do not share personal medical information, medical history or any other specific details about a person's medical symptoms, condition.... Full disclaimer and more information about this site [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer).")
- There is a similar disclaimer also on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). ("Law Stack Exchange is for [educational purposes only](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.")
- A banner on [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). ("Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/why-cant-i-ask-for-personal-advice).") This one is a bit different from Law and Medical Science - since it doesn't link to `site/help/disclaimer`. It seems that it was [inspired by a similar banner](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5952) on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/).
- As a temporary change, a small banner congratulating to the 10th anniversary was shown on some sites: [When is the "happy anniversary" banner displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377095)
- There is a related discussion here: [Wanted: A standard way for a site to have a prominent professional advice disclaimer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104821). But since that post is from 2011, I assume that some of the information given there might be outdate.

In all cases mentioned above, it was something located in a banner in the right sidebar.

**Main question.** Is this banner the place where a site can include some information different from the default setup? If users from some community want to include something here, is the right process to post a feature request on their per-site-meta?

Apart from that, other things that I have seen different on some sites from others that I saw are:

- Omitting HNQs from the frontpage - although there are only a few sites modified like this: [Which sites show recent badges on the frontpage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363255)
- Removing some badges from the list of recently awarded badges. See also: [Remove 'Autobiographer' from Recent Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376601#376992)

**Additional question.** What other things on the front page can be customized for some Stack Exchange site?

Comment: [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) has the picture of the week I think.

Comment: @rene true, and Arqade has Screenshot of the Week.

Comment: Side note: 6-8 years ago each site featured a more custom design, I loved different up/down vote buttons per site, [e.g. that was absolutely gorgeous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252685/i-want-to-have-those-voting-animations-like-on-android-se-pretty-please), and now that’s how [it looks today](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting), like literally miles away

Comment: [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) has site statistics in the sidebar (IIRC *all* beta sites used to have those as well), [private betas](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) have an "Invite fellow experts" form, [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) has a "Get Started" widget. This may be worth turning into a community-curated FAQ, not unlike [What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232)

Answer (score 1):

As with almost anything, reaching community consensus on your per-site meta, and then tagging that post with [status-review] by a moderator is the way to go to get something done by the CM's.

If it is an already pre-existing element in the networks design, as you've listed above, I see no reason why it couldn't be switched on to any given site when that site has described an appropriate use-case for the feature. It might be that it would take some work by a developer, instead of something the CM's could do themselves. For that reason it could get declined by CM's, but I feel that that would be a case-by-case judgement on how "valuable" the addition is to a given site, and how much work it would actually take a dev to make the changes needed.